# Parallel rendering in DirectX 9 in WPF application

Tags: directx9

I want to know if it is possible to have parallel rendering in DirectX 9.0. I am working on a WPF application which uses DirectX 9.0 for rendering. To make my application more efficient I want to have parallel rendering capability in my application if possible. When I try to render from multiple threads, it gives me an Direct3D exception. Is there any way to do this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct3D9 does not support rendering from more than one thread at once. The best you can do is render from a non-GUI thread.

However, there *are* operations which can be done outside D3D9, for example, computing world matrices, or copying into vertex buffers, which can be parallelised. However, anything that involves calling into a D3D9 API cannot ever be multi-threaded.

Comment: Bingo. All the massively parrallel you could ever dream of happens on the video card, not in front of it.